# When scheduling Jenkins job execution, is it possible to specify which parameter to use?

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-plugins, schedule

I'm currently using Jenkins to schedule parameterized jobs. One of them contains an Active Choices parameter that generates a list of parameter values to choose from.

Is there a way to specify the default value I want for this parameter when I schedule my job?

Hope the question is clear enough...

Comment: could you please provide images, to make question more clear?

Answer (score 1):

If you still wish to use the Active Choices Parameter it will default to the **first parameter** of your list when scheduled. So when having the options list:

```
['ONE:selected','TWO:selected','TREE:selected','FOUR:selected']
```

When executed by timer(scheduled) parameter will default to:

```
ONE:selected
```

This behavior was described by the author of this plugin here:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33473

Answer (score 0):

If the job is scheduled within itself the *first* value of the Active Choices Parameter values becomes the default value.

The default value selection described in [Active Choices Plugin, Making 'Default' selections](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin#ActiveChoicesPlugin-Making%27Default%27selections): add the suffix `:selected` to a value, works on manual builds only.

A solution to this is to:

1. Create an upstream job to your job.
2. Schedule this upstream job accordingly.
3. <kbd>**Add Post-build Action**</kbd> → *Trigger parameterized build on other projects*:

   *Projects to build*: `Your downstream project`

   supplied by the [Parameterized Trigger plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).
4. <kbd>**Add Parameters**</kbd> → *Predefined parameters*

   *Parameters*: `ParameterNameInYourDownstreamProject=DefaultValue`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, this is my workaround for setting a default value:

```
def list = ['ONE:selected','TWO:selected','TREE:selected','FOUR:selected']
def listAsString = list.join(',')
def defaultValues = listAsString.replace(':selected','') 
def selectedValues = listAsString.tokenize(',') 
return  [defaultValues] + selectedValues
```

it will return the following list:

```
[ONE,TWO,TREE,FOUR, ONE:selected, TWO:selected, TREE:selected, FOUR:selected]
```

In that case, the first option in the UI will be "ONE,TWO,TREE,FOUR", so in case of timer trigger, it would be the default value.
In case you trigger manually, the separated values would be selected by default.